# Problem when sending file via ajax

Tags: ajax

I am trying to send a file via ajax but I get a 400 bad request error.
My code

```
data.coverQuestions.medicalMalpractice.file = docFile.prop('files')[0];

$.ajax({
url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
method: 'post',
data: {
  action: 'insurance_form_data',
  data,
},
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success (res){
    console.log(res);
}
});
```

If remove the parameters and do not send files, then in this case it is successfully sent.

`contentType: false` `processData: false`

What could be the problem?

Comment: There may be legal issues with submitting medical records and insurance data into a WP site, especially in the EU and UK, that data needs to be securely held and storing it in an unencrypted custom table or posts may not be enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you have a form:

```
<form name="post" id="post-form" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <input type="text" name="last_name">
    <input id="file" type="file" name="featured_image">
</form>
```

Now you have to pass the FormData object to 'data' parameter in ajax

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#post-form').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);

        file_data = $('#file').prop('files')[0]; //get the file
        form_data = new FormData(); //form_data is a FormData() object 
        form_data.append('featured_image', file_data); //append the file in form_data object
        form_data.append('action', 'insurance_form_data'); // your wordpress function name
        form_data.append('post_data', form.serialize()); // e.g. other form data such as first_name, last_name will be stored as serialized

        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Now in PHP file you can test data as:

```
function insurance_form_data() {
    print_r($_POST);
    print_r($_FILES);
}
```

Comment: In order to send a file, the data must first be inserted into an object of the FormData () class; otherwise, does it not work?

Comment: I have a very large form and a lot of fields, which I collect into one object and send to the server, but now, after inserting this object into the FormData object, an empty [Object object] property comes to the backend. What is the best way for me to do that in a convenient way to deliver everything to the server, including files? http://prntscr.com/trbnph - screenshot that displays the size of the form

Comment: To send file to PHP script you have to use the FormData object and are you seeing this line in above code: form_data.append('post_data', form.serialize());

That will serialize all (except files) form data into a single variable "post_data" and then under your PHP function your can get that variable and do parse_str() to convert serialize data in an array.

Comment: I forgot to add this statement "var form = $(this);" i have updated the code.

Comment: I don't have a form, everything is much more complicated there, the data goes through many checks, I didn't even use the form tag. How do I send a data object to the server? Because now it is displayed on the server - [Object object]

Comment: You only hared the JS code, so I don't know how you are taking inputs.Though sending file via AJAX you have to use the FormData() object like I showed above. Maybe try (Google) some jQuery library that can send file with the other data.